# Why is my form not saving? form_for question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this form. I am new to rails and I am trying to write a simple ecommerce site. This is the only part not working. (It worked 2 days ago I sear)

```
<%= form_tag line_items_path do%>
<%binding.pry%>
<%= hidden_field_tag :lite_item, :order_id, @order.id%>
<%= hidden_field_tag :line_item, :menu_item_id, @menu_item.id%>
<%= number_field_tag :line_item, :quantity, 1 %>
<%= submit_tag "Add to Cart"%>
<% end %>
```

It gives params that look like:

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"authenticity_token"=>"VECKnS5SBot1rCyekepPXZa7TyTYkfFi0KdNRTB617ZnelmQo8Lkz_cJmQ8nAmCHUdDlPu1mpkhrPvMKysfjew", "order_id"=>"1", "menu_item_id"=>"1", "quantity"=>"1", "commit"=>"Add to Cart", "controller"=>"line_items", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

The controller for the view looks like this:

```
class MenusController < ApplicationController
   def index
@menu_items = MenuItem.all
end
def show
  @menu_item = MenuItem.find(params[:id])
  @line_items = current_order.line_items.build
end
```

end

The form is really going through the line_items controller

```
 def create
    binding.pry
    @line_item = LineItem.create(line_item_params)
    if @line_item.save
        @order.line_item_id = @line_item.id
        @order.save
        redirect_to cart_path(@current_cart), notice: "Item added to cart."
    else
        redirect_to menu_path(@menu_item), alert: "Item did not add to cart."
    end    
   end
```

With strong params like this

```
 def line_item_params
    params.require(:line_item).permit(:menu_item_id, :quantity, :order_id)
end
```

It should use the line_items_path POST>

If anything else is needed just ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an error being produced?

Comment: yes sorry.
undefined method `merge' for 1:Integer

Comment: I would just edit the question to include that, if you have like a full trace or the whole sentence that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems here.

The signature is [`hidden_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag).  So the parameters you would actually be creating with that form is:

```
{
  "lite_item" => "order_id", # check your spelling...
  "line_item" => "quantity"
}
```

Oops. And that not even going to happen as `<%= number_field_tag :line_item, :quantity, 1 %>` will raise since you're passing an integer where the method expects a hash.

If you really have to create the inputs manually you would want:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "line_item[order_id]", @order.id %>
```

But since you actually have a model there is no reason why you should be using `form_tag` instead of `form_for(@line_item)` or `form_with(model: @line_item)`.

```
<%= form_for(@line_item) do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :order_id %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :menu_item_id %>
  <%= form.number_field :quantity %>
  <%= form.submit_tag "Add to Cart"%>
<% end %>
```

The controller should also use the correct pluralization for the instance variable:

```
def show
  @menu_item = MenuItem.find(params[:id])
  @line_item = current_order.line_items.build
end
```

Your create method is also pretty questionable. All you should need is:

```
def create
  # use .new not .create
  @line_item = LineItem.new(line_item_params)
  if @line_item.save
    redirect_to cart_path(@current_cart), notice: "Item added to cart."
  else
    redirect_to menu_path(@menu_item), alert: "Item did not add to cart."
  end    
end
```

I have no idea why you think you need to update `@order` here. Your controller should just really be adding a row to what is essentially a join table.

Comment: If this answers your question you should accept the answer.